# Were Christians martyred in the Colosseum?

Tags: catholicism, papacy, colosseum

I have been reading some history about the largest standing amphitheater in the world, *The Colosseum.* I read that **Pope Benedict XIV** consecrated the structure because many Christians were supposedly martyred in it despite there being no historical evidence to support that claim. It is natural to conceive the idea that Rome was originally hostile to Christians centuries before its first-ever Christian Emperor, **Constantine**. Is it true that the Romans put Christian converts in Rome inside the Colosseum alongside wild animals to be eaten alive?

Their crime being **failing to pay reverence to Roman gods**

Many graphic depictions of this have been done and most allege that the Roman emperor Nero did it.

[image: Illustration of the Colosseum with Christians about to be attacked by lions, and other animals]

In the case of Polycarp, who was burned alive, the people of Smyrna are even said to have joined in enthusiastically to find wood for the fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Were Christians martyred in the Colosseum?**

The short answer is **yes**, but it was not wide spread as most would believe.

In the colosseum at Rome, we know of two martyrs within the this colosseum.

> They are called Senen and Abdon, and of them we know only that, the names. They were martyred at the Colosseum in the middle of the 3rd century, and it is believed that they were from Persia.
>
> Rosella Rea:
>
> Rome Colosseum
>
> > They were two Persians who they had dedicated  a chapel to inside the Colosseum, a chapel of course that no longer exists.
>
> The director of the Colosseum explains that other places, like the Circus Maximus, produced more martyrs. **However, it was the Colosseum that became the symbol of persecution in a very concrete moment of history, during the pontificate of Benedict XIV.** He established the famous tradition of performing the Way of the Cross there every Good Friday.
>
> Rossellini Rea
>
> Rome Colosseum
>
> > The tradition of doing the Via Crucis here was born when Benedict XIV consecrated the Coliseum, where we now find ourselves. They placed the Stations of the Cross on the sand and in the center they placed a great cross. Every year on Good Friday the pope celebrates the Way of the Cross here.
>
> Today the Via Crucis is one of the most anticipated traditions during Holy Week in Rome. The challenges of today are recalled, and the persecutions of Christians are mentioned, just as in the days of Senen and Abdon.
>
> [The only two martyrs at the Colosseum in Rome](https://www.romereports.com/en/2017/03/05/the-only-two-martyrs-at-the-colosseum-in-rome/)

Wikipedia has the following to say about Saints [Abdon and Sennen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdon_and_Sennen):

> Abdon and Sennen, variously written in early calendars and martyrologies Abdo, Abdus, and Sennes, Sennis, Zennen, are recognized by the Catholic Church and Eastern Orthodox Church as Christian martyrs, with a feast day on 30 July.[2] In some places they have been honoured on 20 March, and the first Sunday of May.
>
> **Veneration**
>
> Their Acts, written for the most part prior to the 9th century, describe them as Persian nobles, captured and taken to Rome during a military campaign in the third century. There they became slaves, converted to Christianity and helped bury the Christian dead. **They came to the attention of Emperor Decius who had them taken in chains before the Roman Senate, where they refused to sacrifice to the Roman gods, and so were dismembered by gladiators in the Colosseum approximately in the year 250**. The Acts certainly contain several fictitious statements about the cause, the circumstances of their coming to Rome and the nature of their torments. They relate that their bodies were buried by a subdeacon, "Quirinus", and later transferred in the reign of Constantine the Great (reigned 306–337) to the Cemetery of Pontianus on the road to Porto, near the gates of Rome.
>
> A fresco found on a sixth century sarcophagus supposed to contain their remains represents them receiving crowns from Christ. Several cities, notably Florence and Soissons, claim possession of their bodies, but the Acta Sanctorum insist that they rest in the Basilica of San Marco Evangelista al Campidoglio, Rome, having been brought there in 1474. They may have even had their own church in Rome, which has now been lost. The Benedictine Abbey of Sainte-Marie in Arles-sur-Tech, France also claims their tomb.
>
> Abdon and Sennen are patron saints of Calasparra, in Murcia, Spain. The feasts days celebrated in their honor in this Spanish town date back to the 16th century.

Comment: Nero particularly did it, this wa before freedom of worship was declared across the empire